# Are questions for service providers welcome at our site?

Tags: discussion, scope

We already have [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](/q/675/185) where the consensus was: Web-Apps are OK, but asking for hosting providers is off-topic. [Are web service recommendations off-topic?](/q/44/185) comes to a similar conclusion, but could be misinterpreted in the context of my question here. There's also [Is requesting a service (that has a software part) on-topic?](/q/2627/185)

I'd say we need this on a more generic basis, as there are questions popping up asking for VPN providers etc.

So what is our stance concerning questions asking for "service providers" – not WebApps, but things like VPN providers, DNS providers etc – whether they have their own client software or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in most of the above mentioned question implicitly or even half-was explicitly: SR is about recommending *software,* not providers/companies. So asking for a service provider (be it VPN, DNS, web/file hosting or whatever) should be considered **off-topic.**

For the distinction of what makes a web-app (and thus an on-topic question), see [Gilles' answer here](/a/45/185) including the discussion on it.

Comment: but usually, the competitions between providers will lead to different software features, especially if price is considered to be a feature, thus making asking for a software satisfying a list of features equivalently asking for providers?

Comment: Not necessarily, @Ooker. That might sometimes be a side-effect, but not the purpose. Asking for different eggs doens't imply looking for a bird :)